# Zabbix MSSQL Monitoring - Failed: cannot extract value from json by path

Tags: sql-server, zabbix

I already create new host on zabbix 5.0 LTS For monitoring SQL Server (2012).
I using default template from zabbix (Template DB MSSQL by ODBC).

this macros I set on host

```
{$MSSQL.DSN} => devdb
{$MSSQL.INSTANCE} => DBDEV115\DBDEV115
{$MSSQL.PASSWORD} => passworduserdb
{$MSSQL.PORT} => 4019
{$MSSQL.USER} => zabbix
```

after that I see on each items i got error message like this

```
Failed: cannot extract value from json by path "$[?(@.object_name=='DBDEV115\DBDEV115:Databases' && @.counter_name=='Transactions/sec' && @.instance_name=='dbColaFlakes')].cntr_value.first()": unsupported construct in jsonpath starting with: "'DBDEV115\DBDEV115:Databases' && @.counter_name=='Transactions/sec' && @.instance_name=='dbColaFlakes')].cntr_value.first()"
```

this error impact from instance name ?
or zabbix doesn't support ?

because i got instance name from query like this

`select @@servername`

Comment: I had the same error and I don't know how to fix it. Did you get any solution? My Zabbix is 5.2 and the macro configuration is the same as yours.

Comment: Hello my friend! You have to post your MACRO Instance like MSSQL$DBDEV115 and your problem will be resolve. Good Luck!

Comment: i still got error because this `unsupported construct in jsonpath starting with: "'DBDEV115\DBDEV115:Databases'`

Answer (score 0):

solutions : 
1 - You Must be Find True Instance Name Can Use like this Query mssql :

```
SELECT object_name, counter_name, cntr_value <br>
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters<br>
WHERE [object_name] LIKE '%Buffer Manager%'<br>
AND [counter_name] = 'Page life expectancy'<br>
```

out put must be like this :
[Out Put Query  Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dden4.jpg)

2 - After Find **Object_name** Set in Zabbix {$MSSQL.INSTANCE} Macro.
Like This : [Zabbix Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2ErI.jpg)